# Why Image and Input boxes reacting like text? When Parent div has styling text-align:center

Tags: html, css

I'm was just passing my time by working on random code of HTML and CSS where I have a **div** which has class `.box` and has an **Image**, **Text** and a Form in it with **input** boxes.

I found that when I provide `text-align: center;` to my parent,  all elements comes in the `center`.
I can't understand what's happening here and why Image and Input boxes react text on `text-align: center;`

here is the codepen link to my code  http://codepen.io/rhulkashyap/pen/MKvzzZ

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto);
body{
  margin:0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;  
}

.box{
    width:500px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    margin:40px auto;
    text-align:center;
    padding:20px;
  border-radius:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="http://minions-2015.gloryone.pl/it/gfx/images/delivery/minion_1.png" alt="" width="200"/>
  <h1>Hello Universe</h1>
  
  <form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username"/> <br />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Password"/> <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
  </form>  

</div>
```

Comment: Child elements inherit from parent(s) elements rules

Comment: Because image and input is the linear elements

Comment: They are "inline-block" elements.

Comment: example of `inline` elements https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements#Elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**From the CSS specification:**

> This property describes how inline-level content of a block container is aligned.  https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#alignment-prop

All `inline` and `inline-block` elements (`input`, `img`) are affected of `text-align`!

You can avoid this by using `display:block;` for the inner elements (like `form`, `h1`, `div`).

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto);
body{
  margin:0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;  
}
.box{
  width:500px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  margin:40px auto;
  text-align:center;
  padding:20px;
  border-radius:5px;
}
input {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="http://minions-2015.gloryone.pl/it/gfx/images/delivery/minion_1.png" alt="" width="200"/>
  <h1>Hello Universe</h1>
  <form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username"/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Password"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
  </form>  
</div>
```

**A Test Case**

```css
div {
  border:1px dashed #000;
  text-align:center;
  width:500px;
}
.block {
  display:block;
}
.inline {
  display:inline;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" value="standard: inline-block">
  <input type="text" class="block" value="with display:block">
  <input type="text" class="inline" value="with display:inline">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you pass text-align: center, it means that the data inside particular div will be placed center according to a rule. Data can be anything, it can be image, text or input box. Your elements are coming in center because all the inline elements are effected by "text-align: center". Please have a look on the following url https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>This is a paragraph. This text has no alignment specified.</p>

<div style="text-align:center;border:1px solid red">
This is some text in a div element!
</div>

<p>This is a paragraph. This text has no alignment specified.</p>

</body>
</html>
```